# Jquery - change css to a html pulled from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all I will explain how website functions. First of all user clicks on a template and that is pulled from a database into a div. I than have a button and if that button is clicked a div from that pulled template should change a color. I will now further explain that with a code:

Template pulled:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Template 1</title>
        <link href="http://localhost/fyproject/public/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <button id="realButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ></button>
    <input id="logo_upload" type="file" id="files" visbility="hidden" style="opacity: 0;"/>

    </div>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>
<div  contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh"><p>hlo</p></div>
<div id="comments">
<form name="forma">
<textarea name="commentUser" id="commentUser" class="refresh" cols="40" rows="5">
Comments here...
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" id="send-data" /><!--onClick="writeComment(e);"--> 
<div id ="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true">
  This text can be by the user.
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Main page where button and template is:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Website Builder')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/template.js') !!}"></script>
        @section('content') 
        <div class= "container template_class ">
            @foreach ($templates as $template)
        <a class="content-link" href="{{ asset($template->file )}}">
        <img id = "image" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
        </a>
        @endforeach
        <button id="color">hello</button>
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
<div id="content-link2"></div>
    </body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/template.js') !!}"></script>
</html>
@endsection
@show
```

So once template is clicked it is inserted inside div id="content-link2"

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.content-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content-link2').load($(this)[0].href, function() {
                    $('#content').draggable({
                    containment: "#content-link2",
                    scroll: false
                });
            });
        });
    return false;
});
$('#h').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
               var code = document.getElementById('content-link2').innerHTML;
            console.log(code);
});
function writeComment(e) {
    var comment = document.forma.commentUser.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML = comment;
}
document.getElementById("content-link2").onmousedown = function() {mousedown()};
document.getElementById("content-link2").onmouseup = function() {mouseup()};
function mousedown() {
   var code2 = document.getElementById("content-link2").innerHTML;
    console.log(code2);
}
function mouseup() {
   var code2 = document.getElementById("content-link2").innerHTML;
    console.log(code2);
}
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
}
$(document).ready ( function(){
        $('#color').click(function(){
        $('#content-link2 > p').css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
   });
});
```

And once button is pressed, whatever is inside div id="content-link2 with p tag I want to apply some css doesn't matter what it is. However now when I click a button nothing happens.

Can someone post some suggestions or solutions?

Comment: so, you are adding the content in `div` with `id=content-link2`?

Comment: Have a look at my js, i am pulling html from database and insert that into div with id=content-link2, I then want to change whatever is inside with a button click, in this example change paragraph background color

Comment: are you getting any error in the browser console?

Comment: Nope console looks empty

Answer (score 0):

After you pull the template and render it into the div id="content-link2" call these lines again in your javascript,

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
});
```

Comment: Do you get any JS error? What is the output if you try alert($("p").length); inside button click function.

Comment: I do not get any alert

Comment: Edit output on alert is 2

Comment: That means there are 2 p tags in your html. Your code to set the css is correct. This should set the css for those 2 p tags. Could you please create a jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
   $('#color').click(function(){
      $('#content-link2 > p').css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"})
   });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('body').on("click", 'button', function(){
        $("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
    });
});
```